# How to manually create gaps for the contour lines?

Tags: plotting, labeling, style

I'm wondering if there is any way to manually create gaps for the contour lines so that the contour labels can be put in the middle of these gaps.

I try to make contour labels in the style like the following ones.

[image]

[image]

Here is a toy example from the Mathematica online manual.

```
ListContourPlot[Table[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -3, 3, 0.1}, {y, -3, 3, 0.1}], ContourLabels -> All]
```

Could you please share you solutions for making the "Gap-style" contour labels in a color plot? Many thanks!

Comment: By the way, "manually" is not the right term here.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Many thanks for sharing your solution. I'll try to learn from your codes. I'm a starter of computer language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

A bit kludgy:

```
    SetOptions[ContourPlot, Frame -> None];
    f[x_, y_] := x/Exp[x^2 + y^2]; (* plug in your function *)
theColors = 
     ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
      ContourStyle -> None];
theContours = 
      ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
       ContourLabels -> (Text[
           Framed[" ", FrameStyle -> Directive[White]], {#1, #2}, 
           Background -> White] &), 
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, White]];
theLabels = 
      ContourPlot[f[x, y], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ContourLabels -> All, 
       ColorFunction -> Function[None], ContourStyle -> None];
ImageMultiply[ImageMultiply[theColors, theContours], theLabels]
```

Comment: Hi David, your plot looks pretty good. However, when I try to export this figure with the codes, the codes give me a very low-resolution result no matter how I set the resolution option. I'll give it a try on other machines. I don't know whether or not "ImageMutiply" will return us a raster result.

Comment: Try `Rasterize` with `RasterSize->1000`.