# Color that *imposes* transparency

Tags: plotting, export, style

Suppose I have a plot with a **transparent** background and I want to place a letter right on top of a curve. For clarity, I'd like to add an outline around the letter. The image below shows a white outline, but I want the outline to match the transparent background. How can that be accomplished? In other words, is there a way to "paint" with transparency, i.e. to "erase"?

[image]

Comment: What's the code you used to generate your figure? Try `Graphics[Text[Style["A", Large]], Background -> Transparent, {0, 0}]`

Comment: You'd be better off exporting to photoshop and doing this there - otherwise you'd have to rasterize and use ImageAdd/ImageSubtract.

Comment: @DerekH I need to erase the two lines around the A.

Comment: "outline around the letter" or *border* around the letter?

Comment: Outline, I think

Comment: Related: "[Imposing breaks in contours in a ContourPlot without rasterization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252802/280)."

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can use [`Region`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Region) functionality to erase portions of the primitives, although it may be slow. Here is some code that does this:

```
ErasePrimitives[prims_, region_] := prims /. r_?RegionQ :> erasePrimitive[r, region]

erasePrimitive[p:Polygon[{__?MatrixQ}], region_] := ErasePrimitives[Thread[p], region]

erasePrimitive[prim_, region_] := Which[
    RegionDisjoint[region, prim],
    prim,
    
    RegionWithin[region, prim], 
    Nothing,
    
    True, 
    Replace[
        RegionDifference[prim, region], 
        b_BooleanRegion :> DiscretizeRegion[b, MeshCellStyle->{0->None}]
    ]
]
```

Example graphic:

```
prim = {Disk[{.5,.1},.2], Line[{{-1,0},{1,0}}], Line[{{0,-1},{0,1}}]};
Graphics[prim]
```

[image]

Erase some portions, and add text:

```
erased = ErasePrimitives[prim, RegionUnion[Disk[{0, 0}, .1], Disk[{.5, 0}, .2]]];
Graphics[
    {
    erased,
    Text[Style["A", 24], {0, 0}],
    Text[Style["C", 48], {.5, 0}]
    },
    Background->LightBlue
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, Carl! I think that this gives more than enough to be customizable by the OP to do precisely what they want to do. I think it is not too complicated to turn the lettering into a region (as I have seen this before with a 3D billboard here, iirc) and take only the border/outline as one sees fit to use, and apply this `ErasePrimitives` function!

Answer (score 2):

The core idea is to use white throughout and then replace *all* the white with a transparent color.

```
myA = Graphics[{Thickness[0.02], Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}}],
      Text[Style["A", 24, Background -> White], {.5, 0}]},
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {-.2, .2}}];

final = ColorReplace[myA, White -> Directive[Opacity[0], White]];

Show[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "House"}], final]
```

[image: line, A on transparent background atop photo]

Comment: Will this preserve the vector quality of the plot?

Comment: Alas, no it won't.  The best way forward, then, is to manually crop the obscured lines (draw two half-lines with a split), and use `Background ->Directive[Opacity[0], White]` for the text.  OR... make everything very high resolution.