# How to make transparent markers without plotted lines going through them?

Tags: plotting, opacity, grid-lines, marker

This is what happens when I use `FaceForm[Opacity[0, White]]`. The lines go across the markers:

[image]

**How can I make the markers transparent inside, but so that the lines don't go through them (just connect on both sides of the markers)?**

Initially, I used `FaceForm[White]`, but then the grid lines behind the markers are not visible:

[image]

```
data = {Table[{x, 1 + 2 x}, {x, 0, 5, 1}], 
   Table[{x, 1 + x}, {x, 0, 5, 1}]};
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar"};
colors = {Blue, Red};
Graphics[Table[{colors[[i]], Line[data[[i]]], 
   FaceForm[Opacity[0, White]], 
   EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[2], JoinForm["Miter"]}], 
   ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][markers[[i]], Offset[7], 
    data[[i]]]}, {i, Length[data]}], AspectRatio -> 1/2, 
 ImageSize -> 450, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

Comment: `The grids are blocked if you fill white.` True. But to tell you the truth, it looks better this way. I do not think the grid lines showing under the markers will look better. But ofcourse, it is your choice.

Comment: @Nasser yes, it looks better but I want to show a bit more information where they intersect so I wanted to do that way. Probably I can try to manually set so that the grids and markers are not overlapping.

Answer (score 11):

For creating a vector figure, you can start from the third example under the "Scope" section on the [Documentation page for `PolygonMarker`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/PolygonMarker/#nbCollapseContent_2):

```
data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
plotRange = MinMax /@ Transpose[Flatten[data, 1]];
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", 
   "DiagonalFourPointedStar", "FivePointedStar"};
colors = {Blue, Red, Green, Yellow, Orange};
background = Darker@Gray;
gr = Graphics[{Table[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], 
     Line[data[[i]]]}, {i, Length[data]}],
   Table[{colors[[i]], FaceForm[background], EdgeForm[None], 
     ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, 
     Length[data]}],
   {Gray, CapForm[None], AbsoluteThickness[0.5], 
    Table[{InfiniteLine[{x, 0}, {0, 1}]}, {x, Range[0, 10, 1]}],
    Table[{InfiniteLine[{0, y}, {1, 0}]}, {y, Range[-.4, 1, .2]}]},
   Table[{FaceForm[None], 
     EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], JoinForm[{"Miter", 6}]}], 
     ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][markers[[i]], Offset[7], data[[i]]]}, {i, 
     Length[data]}]},
  AspectRatio -> 1/2, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> plotRange, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[.025], Scaled[.05]}, 
  Background -> background, FrameStyle -> White, 
  ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {25, 20}}, GridLines -> Automatic]
```

> [image: output]

Exporting to PDF and looking closer:

```
Export["plot.pdf", gr] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

As you see, the grid lines are over the plotted lines - this is a drawback of this approach. If this drawback is important, try a `Region`-based approach from [the other answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270194/280).

Answer (score 11):

Let us employ the `Region`-based functionality for constructing a vector figure with transparent (empty) plot markers without plotted lines going through them. The advantage of this approach is that the plot markers are really transparent, as opposed to [my previous answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/270181/280), where the transparency was a simulation. The plotted lines do not go through the markers, because the corresponding portions of them are explicitly removed using `RegionDifference`. The parameter `aspectRatio` here defines the aspect ratio of the full plot range area (not of the whole figure), as it [does the option `AspectRatio`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83810/280). The amount of padding may be controlled using the parameters of the `padPlotRange` function (or, alternatively, the full plot range `fullPlotRange` can be set explicitly). The perfect result is achieved when the options `AspectRatio -> aspectRatio` and `PlotRange -> fullPlotRange, PlotRangePadding -> None` are set for the final `Graphics`.

First, define auxiliary functions:

```
Clear[padPlotRange, createLineWithMarkers, createLegend];
(* Uniformly expands the plotting area, taking into account the aspect ratio *)
padPlotRange[padding_ : .05, aspectRatio_ : 1/GoldenRatio][plotRange_] := 
 Transpose[ScalingTransform[
    1 + 2 {padding, padding/aspectRatio}, Mean /@ plotRange][plotRange\[Transpose]]]
(* Generates graphics primitives representing the lines and the markers *)
createLineWithMarkers[{shape_, spec_ : .02}, pts_, fullPlotRange_, 
   aspectRatio_ : 1/GoldenRatio] := 
  Module[{rt, rtBack, markerPrimsResc, linePrimsResc, ptsResc},
   rt = RescalingTransform[fullPlotRange, {{0, 1}, {0, aspectRatio}}]; 
   rtBack = InverseFunction[rt]; ptsResc = rt[pts];
   markerPrimsResc = ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"][shape, spec, ptsResc];
   linePrimsResc = 
    MeshPrimitives[RegionDifference[Line[ptsResc], RegionUnion @@ markerPrimsResc], 
      1] /. _MeshPrimitives :> {};
   Join[linePrimsResc, markerPrimsResc] /. (h : Line | Polygon)[ptsResc_] :> 
     h@rtBack[ptsResc]];
(* Generates graphics primitives representing a legend *)
createLegend[markerSpecs_, labels_, {verticalStep_, labelStep_, lineLength_ : .06}, 
   legendPosition_, styles_, fullPlotRange_, aspectRatio_ : 1/GoldenRatio] := 
  Module[{rt, shifts, protect},
   rt = RescalingTransform[{{0, 1}, {0, aspectRatio}}, fullPlotRange];
   Table[Join[styles[[i]],
      MeshPrimitives[
        RegionDifference[Line[{{-lineLength/2, 0}, {lineLength/2, 0}}], 
         ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"] @@ markerSpecs[[i]]], 1] /. _MeshPrimitives :> {},
      {ResourceFunction["PolygonMarker"] @@ markerSpecs[[i]], Text[protect@labels[[i]], {labelStep, 0}]}] /.
     {protect[l_] :> l, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :>
        (rt[{x, y} + {0, (Length[markers] - i) verticalStep} + legendPosition])},
    {i, Length[markers]}]];
```

Input:

```
(* The data set to plot *)
data = Table[{x, BesselJ[k, x]}, {k, 0, 4}, {x, 0, 10, 0.5}];
(* Labels for the legend *)
labels = Table[Style[Subscript[J, n][z], 15], {n, 0, 4}];
(* Aspect ratio of the whole plot area (doesn't include ImagePadding) *)
aspectRatio = 1/2;
(* Plot markers *)
markers = {"Circle", "ThreePointedStar", "FourPointedStar", "DiagonalFourPointedStar", 
   "FivePointedStar"};
(* Colors for the lines&markers *)
colors = {LightBlue, Red, Green, Yellow, Orange};
(* Backgound image *)
background = 
  Polygon[ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, VertexColors -> 
    RGBColor /@ {{0, 0, 1, .9}, {0, 1, 0, .9}, {1, 0, 0, .9}, {1, 1, 0, .9}}];
```

Plotting:

```
(* Determine the range of the input data *)
dataRange = MinMax /@ Transpose[Flatten[data, 1]];
(* Expand the plot area to fit all the graphics elements. 
This value must be specified as the value for PlotRange *)
fullPlotRange = padPlotRange[.04, aspectRatio]@dataRange;
(* Define full specifications for the markers *)
markerSpecs = Table[{markers[[i]], .02}, {i, Length[data]}];
(* Define styles for the lines and the markers *)
plotStyles = 
  Table[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], CapForm[None], FaceForm[None], 
    EdgeForm[{colors[[i]], AbsoluteThickness[1.5], JoinForm[{"Miter", 6}]}]}, {i, 
    Length[data]}];
(* Generate graphics primitives representing the lines and the markers,
along with the corresponding styling directives *)
plotPrimitives = 
  Table[Join[plotStyles[[i]], 
    createLineWithMarkers[markerSpecs[[i]], data[[i]], fullPlotRange, aspectRatio]], {i, 
    Length[data]}];
(* Generate graphics primitives representing the legend *)
legendPrimitives = 
  createLegend[markerSpecs, labels, {.045, .08, .06}, {.85, .29}, plotStyles, 
   fullPlotRange, aspectRatio];
(* Construct a Graphics object from the set of graphics primitives *)
pl = Graphics[{plotPrimitives, legendPrimitives}, PlotRange -> fullPlotRange, 
  AspectRatio -> aspectRatio, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> White, 
  ImagePadding -> {{25, 5}, {15, 5}}, GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Black, 
  Prolog -> background]
```

> [image: output]

Exporting to PDF and looking closer:

```
Export["plot.pdf", pl] // SystemOpen
```

[image: screenshot]

Looks perfect.

---

Strongly related:

- [How to manually create gaps for the contour lines?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252748/280)
- [Imposing breaks in contours in a ContourPlot without rasterization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252802/280)

Answer (score 6):

> How can I make the markers transparent inside but the lines don't go
> through it

You mean like this? If not, will delete this

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just changed `FaceForm[Opacity[0, White]]` to `FaceForm[Opacity[1, White]]`

Comment: Nope, I want to make the region inside the markers transparent.

Comment: @hana I am having hard time understanding what you want then. Can you draw by on paper how one of the markers will look like then and scan the image?  You said you **do not want the other lines to show below the markers** and the above does it. How else will it look like otherwise?

Comment: @Nasser  Maybe the questioner want `Clip` or `UnFill` the interior of markers. It is ease implement in PostScript  but difficult in Mathematica.

Comment: @cvgmt Ok, thanks. But how would it look different than the above is what I do not see now. i.e. Assuming your method can be done in Mathematica, will the end result look different? I never used Clip and Unfill, so may be if you know how to do, that will be good to see.

Comment: @Nasser When we put the picture onto some color background, the clip or unfill part just the background color instead of white. That is their difference.

Comment: @cvgmt yes, that is what I wanted. The white color hide the background. I want to see the background. If you use the white fill then you can't see the grid lines there.

Comment: @cvgmt I see. But in the example given, the background of the plot is now white. So it makes no difference using your method if I understand it right.

Comment: @Nasser that would hide the grid lines, so they're different when the markers and the grids are overlapping.

Comment: @cvgmt is this the PostScript  you're talking about? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript

Comment: @Nasser When we export the plot to svg ,png or pdf, the background color is not white. We can include such svg ,png  or pdf to a color background to test such features.

Comment: @cvgmt  I just exported the image I showed to pdf and png and also svg, in each case the plot background remained white just as it shows in the notebook itself? May be I misunderstood something. I do understand if one sets the background of the plot explicitly to different color using `Background -> Yellow` for example, then the markers will remain white,. Yes which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @Nasser Sorry for my poor English :)  We can include the output.pdf into TeX to test the feature of Opacity instead of White. `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\begin{document}
\pagecolor{yellow!30!orange}
\includegraphics{output.pdf}
\end{document}`

Comment: @Nasser is it still confusing? I think I explained above. The problem is when the markers are on the grid lines so if you use white then they will block the grids.

Comment: @cvgmt is this the PostScript you're talking about? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostScript